# Deployment fails for SQL Server 2014 SP1 Standard on Windows Server 2012 R2 VM

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, sql-server-2014

Apologize in advance - this stuff isn't exactly my wheelhouse.

I'm trying to provision a VM with Windows Server 2012 R2 and setup SQL Server 2014 SP1 Standard using the Azure portal.  I pretty much don't change any of the default settings as I am doing this - even creating a new resource group, VNet, etc just for this server and DB instance.

However, the deployment continues to fail when it gets around to installing SQL Server.   I get the following error message:

> statusCode:Conflict
>   statusMessage:{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","message":"The
>   resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
>   'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"VMExtensionProvisioningError","message":"VM
>   has reported a failure when processing extension 'dscExtension'. Error
>   message: \"DSC Configuration 'PrepareSqlServer' completed with
>   error(s). Following are the first few: Error configuring SQL Server
>   settings PowerShell DSC resource MicrosoftAzure_xSQLServerSettings
>   failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message:
>   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. The
>   SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed.\"."}]}}

And this, too:

> statusCode: Conflict statusMessage: { "status": "Failed", "error": {
>   "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure", "message": "The resource
>   operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
>   "details": [{ "code": "DeploymentFailed", "message": "At least one
>   resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment
>   operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage
>   details.", "details": [{ "code": "Conflict", "message": "{\r\n
>   \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\":
>   \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource
>   operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n
>   \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\":
>   \"VMExtensionProvisioningError\",\r\n \"message\": \"VM has reported a
>   failure when processing extension 'dscExtension'. Error message:
>   \\"DSC Configuration 'PrepareSqlServer' completed with error(s).
>   Following are the first few: Error configuring SQL Server settings
>   PowerShell DSC resource MicrosoftAzure_xSQLServerSettings failed to
>   execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: You
>   cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. The
>   SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed.\\".\"\r\n }\r\n
>   ]\r\n }\r\n}" }] }] } }

I'm really not sure what could have gone wrong, and my efforts to reasearch these error messages have been pretty fruitless.  Any ideas what might be causing this deployment to fail?

Comment: Is this machine on a virtual network?  What DNS settings are being used?  Are there any other errors in the event logs?

Comment: don't apologize, just ask your question

Comment: @CtrlDot Yes, it's on a virtual network.  No custom DNS, just whatever Azure does by default when it creates a VM. Really, all I'm using is the default deployment script that Azure creates for you in "New > Marketplace > Everything > SQL Server."  I haven't remoted into the server to check the logs after SQL Server setup fails - I guess I should start there huh :)